# Removing object from array inside the state of React JS component not refresh all DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its not clear for me why I filter array in React component with some DOM changing and this DOM`s changes show in next after deleted component.

Here`s my plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/5zLSClQYCGj3OcbYjVWh?p=preview

When I click remove link of the second comment (by Peter Peterovich) everything is okay:

[image: When I click remove link of the second comment]

But when state array filters I get "Removing..." text on "Alex Alexandrovich" comment:

[image: When state array filters I get "Removing..." text on "Alex Alexandrovich" comment]

Maybe I was wrong with deleting code in callback function:

```
removeComment: function(removedComment) {
    this.setState({
        comments: _.filter(this.state.comments, function(comment) {
            return comment.Id !== removedComment.id
        }),
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
},
```

Or in delete click handler:

```
handleRemoveCommentClick: function(e) {
    var that = this;
    var el = $(e.target);
    el.text('Removing...');
    var deleteCommentPromise = this.api.deleteComment(this.props);
    deleteCommentPromise.done(function() {
        if (_.isFunction(that.props.onCommentRemove)) {
            that.props.onCommentRemove(that.props);
        } 
    });
},
```

Anyway this phenomenon its not clear for me when React refreshes "data-reactid" of components but DOM is not refreshing:

[image: Data-reactid changes]